# What would happen if the DHR jumper was enabled on a Rev A Apple //e?

Tags: apple-ii, graphics

The Apple //e [originally did not support Double HiRes graphics](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1034/what-was-the-change-to-the-apple-e-motherboard-that-allowed-for-double-hires-g) (DHR). The engineers realized they could double their hires and lores X resolution shortly after the introduction of the machine, so the feature is only available on Revision B and later motherboards. However, to use DGR/DHR you needed the Extended 80-Column Card which added 64KB of RAM to the machine in the AUX slot and you had to close a jumper on the card to enable the feature.

While I've seen some screenshots of what happens when DHR is attempted on Rev A machines (basically a horizontally mangled normal HiRes mode), I became curious as to why it required a jumper since it appears to just fail visually otherwise.

Is there something in the firmware which is reflected by the jumper that would otherwise "protect" DHR on a non-Rev A machine? I'm just really curious what the jumper really does since the failure mode on a Rev A machine (with correct jumper setting) simply seems to be the horizontally smushed display.

Comment: My guess is that with the jumper in place it would cause the card to pull pin 55 low in certain or different circumstances.  In Rev B motherboard this forced TEXT processing but in Rev A motherboards it disabled the motherboard's ROMs.

Comment: @RossRidge so I guess the question would evolve into what would happen in that case - would ROM processing of text output cease or something else?